# Parse a simple JSON string

Tags: sql-server

I have the following JSON String stored in table

```
create table #t1 (Caseno int, CaseText text)

insert into #t1 values
(1,'[{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"PCNForEnrollmentCreationDesc","DisplayName":"Header","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"H2","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"PrimaryEntityInformation","DisplayName":"Primary Entity Information","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"","IsDynamic":false,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPrimaryEntityName","DisplayName":"Primary Entity Name","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Mau \"Informatsionnye tekhnologii\"","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPrimaryEntityAddress","DisplayName":"Primary Entity Address","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"123 Main St, ","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPrimaryEntityCity","DisplayName":"Primary Entity City","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Kaliningrad","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPrimaryEntityPhone","DisplayName":"Primary Entity Phone","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"772  322-977","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPrimaryEntityPostalCode","DisplayName":"Primary Entity Postal Code","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"236029","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPrimaryEntityCountry","DisplayName":"Primary Entity Country","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Russia","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"H2","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"PrimaryContactInformation","DisplayName":"Primary Contact Information","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"","IsDynamic":false,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollContactTypeIndividual","DisplayName":"Contact Type","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Individual","IsDynamic":false,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPriContactFirstName","DisplayName":"Given Name: ","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Elena","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPriContactLastName","DisplayName":"Family Name: ","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Andre","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPriContPrimaryEntityCountry","DisplayName":"Primary Entity Country","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Russia","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPriContPrimaryEntityAddress","DisplayName":"Primary Entity Address","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"123 Main St, ","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPriContPrimaryEntityCity","DisplayName":"Primary Entity City","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Kaliningrad","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPriContPrimaryEntityPhone","DisplayName":"Primary Entity Phone","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"772  322-977","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPriContEmailAddress","DisplayName":"Email Address","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"info@us.me","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"EnrollPriContDataLanguage","DisplayName":"Data Language","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Russkij","IsDynamic":true,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":null,"IsRequired":null},{"RowType":"KV","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"PCNforEnrollPrimaryEntity","DisplayName":"PCN for Enrollment Primary Entity","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"123455","IsDynamic":false,"IsDependent":false,"DependentKey":null,"IsRecurrence":false,"RecurrenceKey":null,"Section":null,"Table":null,"DataType":null,"UIOrder":2,"LookupSelectField":null,"LookupFilterField":null,"col3":null,"col4":null,"col5":null,"col6":null,"col7":null,"col8":null,"col9":null,"col10":null,"col11":null,"col12":null,"col13":null,"FieldType":"FreeText","IsRequired":"true"},{"RowType":"H2","s1":0,"s2":0,"s3":0,"TableNo":0,"FieldName":"NoticesEntityInformation"')
```

I want to extract the value from the string and present this way:

```
Caseno          FieldName                       FieldValue  
1               Header                      
1               Primary Entity Information                      
1               Primary Entity Name             Mau \"Informatsionnye tekhnologii   
1               Primary Entity Address          123 Main St,    
1               Primary Entity City             Kaliningrad 
1               Primary Entity Phone            772  322-977    
1               Primary Entity Postal Code      236029  
1               Primary Entity Country          Russia  
1               Primary Contact Information                     
1               Contact Type                    Individual  
1               Given Name:         Elena   
1               Family Name:         Andre   
1               Primary Entity Country          Russia  
1               Primary Entity Address          123 Main St,    
1               Primary Entity City             Kaliningrad 
1               Primary Entity Phone            772  322-977    
1               Email Address                   info@us.me  
1               Data Language                   Russkij 
1               PCN for Enrollment Primary Entity 123455
```

Basically I want to extract `DisplayName` and `FieldValues`.

Example String: `"DisplayName":"Primary Entity Name","FieldSchemaName":null,"FieldValue":"Mau \"Informatsionnye tekhnologii\""`

Comment: The JSON string posted in your example is incomplete. JSON parsers will mostly error on it. If you're on SQL Server 2016 or later try using [OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql).

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2016+, just parse the JSON with `OPENJSON()` using explicit schema (`WITH` clause). The data in the question is truncated (and the JSON is not valid), but the following example is a working solution:

Table and JSON (fixed and simplified):

```
create table #t1 (Caseno int, CaseText text)
insert into #t1 values
(1,'[
   {
      "RowType":"KV",
      "s1":0,
      "s2":0,
      "s3":0,
      "TableNo":0,
      "FieldName":"PCNForEnrollmentCreationDesc",
      "DisplayName":"Header",
      "FieldSchemaName":null,
      "FieldValue":"",
      "IsDynamic":true,
      "IsDependent":false,
      "DependentKey":null,
      "IsRecurrence":false,
      "RecurrenceKey":null,
      "Section":null,
      "Table":null,
      "DataType":null,
      "UIOrder":2,
      "LookupSelectField":null,
      "LookupFilterField":null,
      "col3":null,
      "col4":null,
      "col5":null,
      "col6":null,
      "col7":null,
      "col8":null,
      "col9":null,
      "col10":null,
      "col11":null,
      "col12":null,
      "col13":null,
      "FieldType":null,
      "IsRequired":null
   },
   {
      "RowType":"H2",
      "s1":0,
      "s2":0,
      "s3":0,
      "TableNo":0,
      "FieldName":"PrimaryEntityInformation",
      "DisplayName":"Primary Entity Information",
      "FieldSchemaName":null,
      "FieldValue":"",
      "IsDynamic":false,
      "IsDependent":false,
      "DependentKey":null,
      "IsRecurrence":false,
      "RecurrenceKey":null,
      "Section":null,
      "Table":null,
      "DataType":null,
      "UIOrder":2,
      "LookupSelectField":null,
      "LookupFilterField":null,
      "col3":null,
      "col4":null,
      "col5":null,
      "col6":null,
      "col7":null,
      "col8":null,
      "col9":null,
      "col10":null,
      "col11":null,
      "col12":null,
      "col13":null,
      "FieldType":null,
      "IsRequired":null
   },
   {
      "RowType":"KV",
      "s1":0,
      "s2":0,
      "s3":0,
      "TableNo":0,
      "FieldName":"EnrollPrimaryEntityName",
      "DisplayName":"Primary Entity Name",
      "FieldSchemaName":null,
      "FieldValue":"Mau \"Informatsionnye tekhnologii\"",
      "IsDynamic":true,
      "IsDependent":false,
      "DependentKey":null,
      "IsRecurrence":false,
      "RecurrenceKey":null,
      "Section":null,
      "Table":null,
      "DataType":null,
      "UIOrder":2,
      "LookupSelectField":null,
      "LookupFilterField":null,
      "col3":null,
      "col4":null,
      "col5":null,
      "col6":null,
      "col7":null,
      "col8":null,
      "col9":null,
      "col10":null,
      "col11":null,
      "col12":null,
      "col13":null,
      "FieldType":null,
      "IsRequired":null
   }
]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT t.CaseNo, j.*
FROM #t1 t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.CaseText) WITH (
   DisplaydName varchar(100) '$.DisplayName',
   FieldValue varchar(100) '$.FieldValue'
) j
```

Result:

```
CaseNo  DisplaydName                        FieldValue
1       Header  
1       Primary Entity Information  
1       Primary Entity Name                 Mau "Informatsionnye tekhnologii"
1       Primary Entity Address              123 Main St, 
1       Primary Entity City                 Kaliningrad
1       Primary Entity Phone                772  322-977
1       Primary Entity Postal Code          236029
1       Primary Entity Country              Russia
1       Primary Contact Information 
1       Contact Type                        Individual
1       Given Name:                         Elena
1       Family Name:                        Andre
1       Primary Entity Country              Russia
1       Primary Entity Address              123 Main St, 
1       Primary Entity City                 Kaliningrad
1       Primary Entity Phone                772  322-977
1       Email Address                       info@us.me
1       Data Language                       Russkij
1       PCN for Enrollment Primary Entity   123455
```